# Turning encrypted data into a string and back

Tags: string, typescript, encryption, arraybuffer

I would like to store the encrypted data in a string format. Unfortunately I am not able to do that and I don't understand why.

For some reason this line:

```
const str = new TextEncoder().encode(buff1);
```

creates a string with more bytes and different bytes then those in the Arraybuffer before.

The end result of this code is that these are logged to the console:
ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 139 }
ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 262 }

This is a problem since they should have been similar but they are not. I tried a lot of alternatives but all possible ways to do this end up with this same issue. I would really appreciate it if someone can tell me how to fix this.

Note that the EncryptText function works like it should. I only added it for those who would like to run the code into their IDE.

```
async function encryptText(plainText, iv, password): Promise<ArrayBuffer> {
    const ptUtf8 = new TextEncoder().encode(plainText);
    const pwUtf8 = new TextEncoder().encode(password);
    const pwHash = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', pwUtf8);
    const alg = { name: 'AES-GCM', iv: iv };
    const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey('raw', pwHash, alg, false, ['encrypt']);
    return crypto.subtle.encrypt(alg, key, ptUtf8);
};

async function encrBuffToUtf8Test() {
    const plainData = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, ' +
        'sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.';
    const password = 'infamous';
    const randomValues = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12));

    const encryptionResult1 = await this.encryptText(plainData, randomValues, password);

    const buff1 = Buffer.from(encryptionResult1);
    const str = new TextEncoder().encode(buff1);
    const utf8buff = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(buff);
    const encryptionResult2 = utf8buff.buffer;
    const resTest = encryptionResult1 === encryptionResult2;
    if (!resTest) {
        console.log(encryptionResult1);
        console.log(encryptionResult2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I write this as an answer almost every day, but once again, [you can't convert arbitrary binary data to a string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences) using standard character encodings.  It simply does not work that way.

Consider using base64 or hex instead.

Comment: So; when I asked this question yesterday I was deep into the night and I was way more frustrated by this problem then I should have been (I also spend way more time on this problem then I should have). I was a bit blunt/rude in my response to you wich is why I deleted them. I would like to apologize for my reaction.

Comment: @MaestroMaus No worries.  We've all been there, thanks for taking the time to respond and apologize.  It's always appreciated :)  Did you solve your problem in the end?

Comment: Part of the frustration I had yesterday is that I already tried base64/hex encoding. The problem with this is that a lot of the solutions of base64 and hex encoding start off from a point where you have a plain string and won't work when you have an encrypted array of bytes like I do. The standard atob/btoa solution won't work either. I think it only accepts ASCII but I am not sure. For those who are looking for a practical solution and are using NodeJS: const b64str = Buffer.from(encryptionResult1).toString('base64');
        const buff2 = Buffer.from(b64str, 'base64');